# Where should I put some operations in functional component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks

I fetched some data from grpahql endpoints.
I have to do some calculation before rendering.
But this code cause browser freeze after so many times of render of this component.
I think I may turn this code to useEffect.
But I can't sure why browser going to freeze and how to modify code to clean and working well.
As you can see, this code is some mistake.
Can you explain how to do it?

```
const StatusBar = () => {
  const { data: curProgram_data } = useQuery(GET_CUR_PROGRAM);
  const { data: programs_data, loading: programs_loading } = useQuery(GET_PROGRAMS);
  const { data: tests_data, loading: tests_loading } = useQuery(GET_TESTS);
  const { data: articles_data, loading: articles_loading } = useQuery(GET_ARTICLES);

  if (programs_loading || tests_loading || articles_loading)
    return <p>Loading ... </p>;

  const { curProgram } = curProgram_data;
  const { programs } = programs_data;
  const totalTests = tests_data.tests;
  const totalArticles = articles_data.articles;

  var startYear = moment(totalTests[0].date, 'YYYY/MM/DD').format('YYYY');
  var endYear = moment(totalTests[totalTests.length - 1].date, 'YYYY/MM/DD').format('YYYY');
  var years = [];
  for(var i = startYear; i <= endYear; i ++)
    years.push(i);

  for(var i = 0; i < programs.length; i ++) // Sort Programs by Date
    for(var j = i + 1; j < programs.length; j ++) {
      if(programs[i].tests[0].date > programs[j].tests[0].date) {
        var temp;
        temp = programs[i];
        programs[i] = programs[j];
        programs[j] = temp;
    }
  }
  console.log("I think we have to turn all variables to state with useEffect"); 

  var programsGroupedByYear = [];
  var eachProgramLength = [];

  var startYear = moment(programs[0].tests[0].date, 'YYYY/MM/DD').format('YYYY');
  var endYear = moment(programs[programs.length - 1].tests[0].date, 'YYYY/MM/DD').format('YYYY');

  for(i = 0; i < endYear - startYear + 1; i ++) {
    programsGroupedByYear[i] = [];
    eachProgramLength[i] = [];
  }

  var isNext = startYear;
  var yearIt = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < programs.length; i ++) { // Group Programs by Year
    var year = moment(programs[i].tests[0].date, 'YYYY/MM/DD').format('YYYY');

    if(year == isNext)
      programsGroupedByYear[yearIt].push(programs[i]);
    else {
      isNext = year;
      yearIt ++;
      programsGroupedByYear[yearIt].push(programs[i]);
    }
  }
  ...  ....

  return (
    <div>
      <YearBar 
        groupLengths = {groupLengths} 
        curProgramPos = {curProgramPos}
        years = {years}
        totalArticles = {totalArticles}
      />

      ....

    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The console log in this component is calling infinitive. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

React presses on the fact that all the dynamic data must be in it's state. This includes even DOM data like form input values. What you're doing here is completely wrong.

There are too many mistakes you're making here

### Mistake 1:

Not using React State. Can't emphasis this enough. All your dynamic data must go into React state - `year`, `totalTests` - everything must be declared as React State. That way React can track the data changes and optimize the performance.

### Mistake 2:

Not using `useEffect()` for performing side effects. Side effect must not be performed at the root of the function. You should not. React will never know what the hell is happening inside your function. Use proper `useEffect()` with proper dependencies array

### Mistake 3:

This one is JavaScript mistake. Do not use `var` for declaring variables. The has scoping issues. Use `let` for variables and `const` for constants.

### Mistake 4:

Not using efficient and in-built JavaScript methods instead of writing your own sorting and other algorithms.

### The console log in this component is calling infinitive. Why?

Because the console.log is at the root of the function. Every time there's an update and when React needs to re-render the component, the function will be called again with the new state values. Since you're code made the function run into infinite loop, it was console logging infinite times. This is why it's much more important to use `useState` and `useEffects`, so that React knows, what to execute and what to update and prevent itself from running into infinite loop.

Hope it answer your questions, Next moving to solution

## Solution

I have to make it clear that I cannot and will not rewrite your entire code and make sure everything works, that's your job, But I however I'm more than happy to help you and explain them.

Before moving to React, let me clear up things in JavaScript space

### Avoid using `var`

`var` are not scoped properly in JavaScript which results in lots of confused and headaches while debugging. So use the new keywords for declaring variables

- `let` for variables
- `const` for constant

They are scoped and behaves as how you expect them to behave.

### If something exists, do not rewrite it - Use in-built methods

Instead of writing your own sorting algorithm, use JavaScript in-built in `sort` method. Embrace **fun**ctional programming

Your sorting algorithm can be replaced as

```js
const sortedPrograms = [ ...programs ].sort((a, b) => 
  a.tests[0].date > b].tests[0].date ? -1 : 1
)
```

The reason why I used `[ ...programs ].sort` instead of `programs.sort` is because `sort` method mutates original array, which isn't desirable in React, that's why I shallow cloned the array.

For the next two for loops I believe you're trying to group the programs based on its year. (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Those tens of lines of codes can be easily replaces by my **favorite** JavaScript's `reduce` method.

Your grouping algorithm can be replaced as

```js
const programsGroupedByYear = programs.reduce(
  // acc - Accumulated, cur - current item
  (acc, cur) => {
    const year = moment(cur.tests[0].date, 'YYYY/MM/DD').format('YYYY');
    return {
      ...acc,
      // Check if the year index exist in the accumulated object
      // if yes, append it to the array
      // if no, create a new array
      // and store in the year index
      [year]: acc[year] ? [ ...acc[year], cur ] : [cur]
    }
  }
, {})
```

That's it, your 20+ lines of two for loops can replaced by 6+ lines of `Array.reduce` method.

### Store all the data in React State

Apollo's `useQuery` is a custom hook, which means the output `data` is a React State. So need of declaring any new state here except for variable to store your sorted data and grouped data.

### Move all the side effects inside `useEffects`

There should not be any side effects at the root of the function. All of them must go inside `useEffects`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // All your side effects goes in here
}, [deps])
// React will track the items in dep array, 
// if there's any change in them, React will call this useEffect
```

If no side effects are allowed at the root of the function, what then should be allowed at the root? That brings us to

### Always use hooks at the root of your function

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

### Final Advice

Use JavaScript as Functional Programming way, especially if you're using React instead of thinking in for loops and data mutation

I highly suggest you use [Rule of Hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) linter plugin.

So wrapping up,

### GIST of your code

```
const StatusBar = () => {
  const { data: curProgram_data } = useQuery(GET_CUR_PROGRAM);
  const { data: programs_data, loading: programs_loading } =
    useQuery(GET_PROGRAMS);
  const { data: tests_data, loading: tests_loading } = useQuery(GET_TESTS);
  const { data: articles_data, loading: articles_loading } =
    useQuery(GET_ARTICLES);

  const [sortedProgram, setSortedProgram] = useState([]);
  const [programsGroupedByYear, setProgramsGroupByYear] =
    useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!programs_loading) {
      const _sortedPrograms = [ ...programs_data.programs ].sort((a, b) => 
        a.tests[0].date > b].tests[0].date ? -1 : 1
       )
      setSortedProgram(_sortedPrograms)

      const _programsGroupedByYear = programs.reduce(
        (acc, cur) => {
          const year = moment(cur.tests[0].date, 'YYYY/MM/DD').format('YYYY');
          return {
            ...acc,
            [year]: acc[year] ? [ ...acc[year], cur ] : [cur]
          }
        }
        , {})
      }
      setProgramsGroupedByYear(__programsGroupedByYear)
  }, [programs_data, programs_loading])


  // Then place your if condition

  if (programs_loading || tests_loading || articles_loading)
    return <p>Loading ... </p>;

  return (
    <YourJSXCode />
  )
}
```

Comment: `var` does not have scoping issues, it is just scoped differently from `let` or `const`

Comment: @Agney Perhaps depends on one's perceptive. For me, when a declare a variable, I expect it to stay inside the block where I declared it. So it's a scope issue for me. But in case of OP, he's clearly harnessing it, using the same `i` in all three `for` loops. But, IMO what OP is doing is wrong.

Comment: I also want to turn all variables into state, but there are too much operations and variables. How can I handle them all?

Comment: I tried to put variables into useState(). But some errors occured. It said that useState run conditionally. In other component, I had to put useState before useQuery. But in this component, I must use useState() after useQuery(). How can I solve it?

Comment: What were the errors?  I shall reply to you after one hour

Comment: Thanks for you consideration. It's hard to explain all things here. Can you help me in spare time?